# SOAPMessage.writeTo() only escapes special chars

Tags: java, soap, escaping, stringescapeutils

I've tried to send some unicode string in a foreign language to the [SOAPMessage.writeTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#writeTo(java.io.OutputStream)) but it didn't escape it.

when i tried to send an XML escaped string [StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.lang.String)) it doubled escape the ampersands.

What is the right way to escape those strings ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape unicode chars in an XML file/stream, only XML entities.
If you want to process unicode xml properly you have to set:

Right response header: `Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`
Right XML declaration: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"`...

and open the response file with a right editor/console.

Comment: `application/xml` is also an option for Content-type to enforce XML declaration